# two unknown, two equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Solving for two variables when you have two equations is relatively easy, but not in this form (check below) so I have this puzzle I want to figure it out, how you approach this:

$$19.7=x(0.69)+y(0.31)$$
$$3.66=\frac{xy}{0.69y +0.31x}$$

Thank you

Comment: Those values seem oddly specific for a "puzzle." Anyway, I'd solve the top equation for $y$ in terms of $x$ and then plug that into the second equation.

Comment: a quick wolfram result you can see here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=19.7%3Dx%280.69%29%2By%280.31%29+and+3.66%3D%28xy%29%2F%280.69y%2B0.31x%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the top equation to solve for $x$. Then substitute that into the bottom equation to solve for $y$. Then solve for $x$ explicitly.

Comment: worked !! thanks